# Extra double quotes with backslashes when marshaling to JSON

Tags: json, go

I'm playing with Go and trying to encode a struct to a json. All is fine exept that when I run my code I get a string of string in the json body response, the code I'm running is this:

```
type LocalTimes struct {
    LocalTimes []DateTime `json:"localTimes"`
}

type DateTime struct {
    Timezone string `json:"timezone"`
    Data     string `json:"date"`
    Time     string `json:"time"`
}

<some code>

responseData, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(apiR.Body)

                var apiC map[string]interface{}

                json.Unmarshal([]byte(responseData), &apiC)

                date, _ := json.Marshal(apiC["date"])
                time, _ := json.Marshal(apiC["time"])

                dt := DateTime{
                    utcTime,
                    string(date),
                    string(time),
                }

                localTimes.LocalTimes = append(localTimes.LocalTimes, dt)

<some code>

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(localTimes)



and the response I get is:


{
    "localTimes": [
        {
            "timezone": "UTC-5",
            "date": "\"2020-11-24\"",
            "time": "\"07:15:41\""
        },
        {
            "timezone": "UTC-4",
            "date": "\"2020-11-24\"",
            "time": "\"08:15:43\""
        },
        {
            "timezone": "UTC-3",
            "date": "\"2020-11-24\"",
            "time": "\"09:15:45\""
        },
        {
            "timezone": "UTC-2",
            "date": "\"2020-11-24\"",
            "time": "\"10:15:47\""
        }
    ]
}
```

I think the problem is with the encode becuse when I print the date, for exemple, I have this:

```
"2020-11-24"
```

But at Json it turns into:

```
"\" 2020-11-24 \ ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the interface to string using:

```
date := apiC["date"].(string)
time := apiC["time"].(string)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are double-encoding those strings. When you unmarshal the input, those fields are decoded as strings. Then you json marshal those strings (which will give you "value"), and then encode them again, which will be ""value"".

Simply do:

```
var date,time string
if value, ok:=apiC["date"]; ok {
  date=fmt.Sprint(value)
}
if value, ok:=apiC["time"]; ok {
  time=fmt.Sprint(value)
}
```

Comment: aren't you missing a type assertion? or does Go now allow to *convert* `interface{}` into a `string`?